# Informatica only insert last data row into database table

Tags: database, oracle, etl, informatica, unixodbc

I am a newbie in informatica tool.
I run a workflow to insert data from database A, table A.A to database B, table B.B. Session did succeed.
And I met a problem in log file:
Database errors occurred:
Execute -- Informatica' ODBC 20101 driver27376073
Execute -- ODBC Driver Manager Function sequence error
When last step to insert data to B.B
It is only 1 row inserted per workflow running time. Example: I have 7 rows, only 1 row inserted and 6 rows rejected.
I search for 27376073 error code but I found nothing about it.
Can anyone help me solve this problem, please?

Comment: This looks like a database problem. Many cases can happen 1. Db has some unique key on certain column(s) and you mapping is producing duplicates based on that column.2. some column may be not null in db so db is rejecting. 3. Some other constraint like goreign key may be  failing.

Answer (score 0):

are you using aggregator transformation cheak groupby port marked or not
and if source is a FF and fixed width we need to do some settings in session task